# Why does the result in Swift Playground differ from being executed in the app?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I have the following code in Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar( calendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar )
let components = calendar.components( NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date )

let dateStrippedOfTimeComponent:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

The result in Playgrounds is 5 Jul 2014 00:00 which is what I want

However the same code, when used in my viewController as part of a func gives the result 04 Jul 2014 23:00 and also the current NSDate() result comes up an hour earlier than it is showing my my mac. Could someone show me how to solve this problem? Much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running the code where it doesn't give the desired result? On an iOS device? Is the time (and time zone) set correctly?

Comment: running it in Xcode 6.0 and the wrong result comes up in the debugger ...

Comment: Yes, are you running it on your Mac or on an iOS device? Or on an iOS simulator?

Comment: Sorry, using the iOS Simulator for iPhone5s

Comment: On the Simulator the calendar is actually Gregorian and the region is set to UK. The time is also showing the same as on my Mac. But the error still occurs ...

Comment: Just a point - on my system I get slightly different answers when using an IOS playground and a Mac OS playground (12:00 am versus 00:00). You're obviously using a Cocoa playground...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's merely a display issue.
The two date objects are the **exactly the same**, but the playground and the app are using two different timezones when printing the result.

`NSDate` is a pure representation of an instant in time.

Whenever you need to display it, then you can decide the format, the locale, the timezone and other visualization-related information. As an example, you can run this in the playground:

```
let date = NSDate()
// "Jul 6, 2014, 11:43 AM" in my system timezone (Italy)

let calendar = NSCalendar( calendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar ) 
let components = calendar.components( NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date )
let dateStrippedOfTimeComponent = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
let estDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateStrippedOfTimeComponent)
// "Jul 5, 2014, 6:00:00 PM" in NYC

dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let utcDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateStrippedOfTimeComponent)
// "Jul 5, 2014, 10:00:00 PM" in London
```

Comment: When I looked at the time zones. The app was correcting for British Summer Time. I just think this is a real problem if the user of the app is in the US - you can't then force the app to think it is in London as other features of the app are linked to the persons default timezone. I came to an intermediate solution by using .secondsFromGMT as this should correct for British summer time

Comment: It depends on the timezone set on the date formatter, which is the system one by default. If you want the date to match the user's timezone you have nothing extra to do, otherwise you can manually specify a timezone